# Почему при прокрутки в низ прокручивается до конца страницы?

Tags: javascript

Есть класс с виртуальным скролом при прокрутки в низ он прокручиваться до конца блока

```js
const list = Array.from(Array(100).keys())


const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
    let timeoutId = null;
    return (...args) => {
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
        callback();
      }, wait);
    };
  }

class VertulList {
    _list = []
    _heightRow = 20
    _visibleRows = 0
    _start = 0

    html = {
        list: null,
        item: []
    }
    constructor({ box, list, heightRow }) {
        this.box = box
        this.list = list
        this.heightRow = heightRow ?? 20
        this.render()
        this.vertulScroll()
        this.handelScroll =  () => {
            const active = Math.floor( this.box.scrollTop / this.heightRow )
    
            const start = Math.min(
                Math.ceil( this.list.length - this.visibleRows - 2  ),
                active < 0 ? 0 : active
            )
            this.start = start
        }
    
        this.box.addEventListener('scroll', this.handelScroll, true)
    }


    get list() {
        return this._list
    }

    set list(arr) {
        this._list = arr
    }

    get heightRow() {
        return this._heightRow
    }

    set heightRow(number) {
        this._heightRow = number
        this.visibleRows = this.box.clientHeight / this.heightRow
    }

    get start() {
        return this._start
    }

    set start(number) {
        this._start = number
        this.vertulScroll()
    }

    activeIndexArray() {
        const visibleRowsCeil = Math.ceil( this.visibleRows )
        const start = Math.ceil( this.start )
        return this.list.slice(start , start + visibleRowsCeil + 2)
    }

    vertulScroll() {
        const activeIndexArray = this.activeIndexArray()
        this.html.item[0].style.marginTop = `${this.getTopHeight()}px`
        this.html.item[Math.ceil( this.visibleRows ) + 1].style.marginBottom = `${this.getBottomHeight()}px`
        for (let i = 0; i < activeIndexArray.length; i++) {
            const el = activeIndexArray[i]
            this.html.item[i].textContent = el
        }
    }

    render() {
        this.html.list = document.createElement('ul')
        this.html.list.classList.add('number-list')


        for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil( this.visibleRows ) + 2; i++) {
            const item = document.createElement('li')
            item.classList.add('number-list__item')
            this.html.list.append(item)
            this.html.item[i] = item
        }
        
        this.box.append(this.html.list)
    }

    getTopHeight() {
        return this.heightRow * this.start
    }

    getBottomHeight() {
        const rowsNotVisible = this.list.length - (this.start + this.visibleRows + 2)

        return (rowsNotVisible * this.heightRow)
    }

}

new VertulList({
    box: document.querySelector('.big'),
    list,
    heightRow: 100,
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.big {
  height: 500px;
  
  overflow: auto;
}
.number-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.number-list__item {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="big">
        <div class="tttt"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А ожидаемый результат какой?